# Every equalizer is monic

Tags: category-theory

Theorem I of section 3.10 of Goldblatt's *Topoi* states that every equalizer is monic. I don't understand the proof given. For reference, it is:

> Suppose $i : e \rightarrow a$ equalizes $f,g : a \rightarrow b$.
>     Suppose $i \circ j = i \circ l$ where $j,l : c \rightarrow e$. Since
>     $$f \circ (i \circ j) = (f \circ i) \circ j = (g \circ i) \circ j = g \circ (i \circ j)$$
>     there exists a unique $k : c \rightarrow e$ such that $i \circ k = i \circ 
>   j$. Hence, $k = j$. Since $i \circ l = i \circ j$, $k = l$.
>     Hence, $j = l$ and $i$ is monic.

I follow Goldblatt up to the derivation of the identity $k = j$. Since $f \circ g = f \circ h$ implies $g = h$ whenever $f$ is monic, but we don't know that $i$ is monic in this case, the identity must be derived in some other way. However, I don't understand what this way is.

Comment: You're applying the universal property of $i$ to see that $k$ is the *unique* morphism $k: c \to e$ such that $i \circ k = i \circ j$ but $j$ is already a morphism $j: c \to e$ such that $i \circ j = i \circ j$, so $j = k$.

Comment: I had read the definition and proof several times, but completely missed that $k$ is *unique*, from which the identities can be derived. Thank you for pointing out this now completely obvious fact.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*This CW answer intends to remove this question from the Unanswered queue.*

---

The [comment by t.b.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81296/every-equalizer-is-monic#comment192086_81296) contains all there is to explain:

> You're applying the universal property of $i$ to see that $k$ is the *unique* morphism $k:c \to e$ such that $i \circ k = i \circ j$ but $j$ is already a morphism $j: c \to e$ such that $i\circ j = i\circ j$, so $j = k$.