# Why does morphism in equalizer have to be monomorphism?

Tags: category-theory

I'm watching this [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtvVHokhSoM&t=1054s) And the lector says that p have to be monomorphism. I've read [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equaliser_(mathematics)#In_category_theory) and it also mentioned there, but no proof is given.

If we use notation from wikipedia article I get that `u` is unique and because of that we have a situation that is similar to monomorphism, but in monomorphism any two morphisms from `O` to `E` that compose with `eq` would have to be equal, not only those which factorize some other morphism.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81296/every-equalizer-is-monic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $eq$ itself equalize $f$ and $g$; thus if $eq\circ v=eq\circ w$, you can define $m=eq\circ v$, and then
$$f\circ m=f\circ eq\circ v=g\circ eq \circ v=g\circ m.$$
The universal property implies that there must be a unique $u$ such that $eq\circ u=m$; but both $v$ and $w$ have this property, thus $u=v=w$.

Comment: Um... whaaat? `eq itself equalize f and g` - okay, that's obviously true. `thus eq * v = eq * w` - what's this `v` and `w`? All what you've said in the end is that `u` is unique. How does that implies that eq is a monomorphism?

Comment: $v$ and $w$ are two morphisms $Z\to E$, and I assume that they satisfy $eq\circ v=eq\circ w$. Then I show that they have to be equal, which shows that $eq$ is a monomorphism.

Comment: Yeah, I get it now, thanks a lot!